# Decimales en SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

necesito saber como poder hacer que los precios salgan así:

```
1,250.00€
```

Ahora en la BD lo tengo puesto así, `decimal(10,2)` y me sale así: `1250.00€`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una cuestión de formato al representar los valores y para ello dispones de la función [FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) de MySQL

Estructura a seguir:

```
SELECT FORMAT(columna, 2) FROM tabla.
```

Sentencia que soluciono el problema al usuario (no conocemos la tabla sql):

```
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Total, FORMAT(SUM(Total), 2) as suma, Fecha,Total FROM pedidos WHERE Estado=1 and Iduser =" . $_GET['ID']);
```

Comment: y como se o aplico a la columna que necesito?

Comment: Pues con un SELECT FORMAT(columna, 2) FROM tabla;

Comment: Si esto ya lo comprobe, pero en esta consulta con count, no me sale.
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Total, sum(Total) as suma, FROM pedidos WHERE Estado=0 and Iduser =" . $_GET['ID']);

Comment: Tenías un error de una coma, además de no haber puesto la llamada a la función FORMAT. Prueba con: $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT FORMAT(Total, 2), FORMAT(SUM(Total), 2) as suma FROM pedidos WHERE Estado = 0 and Iduser = " . $_GET['ID']);

Comment: se me queda en blanco, no funciona @Javier

Comment: Ya lo tengo, 
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Total, FORMAT(SUM(Total), 2) as suma, Fecha,Total FROM pedidos WHERE Estado=1 and Iduser =" . $_GET['ID']);

Comment: Escribe la respuesta tu y te la doy por valida! Gracias @Javier

Comment: ¡Encantado de ayudar! No sé qué puedo poner más como respuesta ya que en tu pregunta no pones la sql. Como mucho puedo poner algo como SELECT FORMAT(columna, 2) FROM tabla. Imagino que puedes dar por válida la respuesta tal y como está. La gente también lee los comentarios si no le queda clara